# if-else statement not working correctly in python for loop

Tags: python, dictionary, if-statement

I have a block of code that I am iterating through a dictionary looking for keywords found and the number of times each is found. The if statement works and returns the expected output if keywords are found. However, the else statement is not working when no keywords are found it should return "No keywords found". This seems simple enough but I just can't put my finger on why this is not working. I'm fairly new to coding, so I apologize if this seems extremely basic.

Here is the code block I'm using:

```
    with open(keyword_file_path, 'r') as file:
        data = file.read()

    kw_found = {}
    for keyword in keywords:
        found = re.findall(keyword, data, re.I)
        if found:
            kw_found[keyword] = len(found)

    for key in kw_found.keys():
        if key in kw_found.keys():
            width = max(len(x) for x in key)
            output_fp.write("{0:<{1}} : {2}\n".format(key, width, kw_found[key]))
        else:
            output_fp.write("No Keywords Found\n")
```

The if statement works and we get the following output if it does find the predefined keywords:

dog : 5

cat : 2

bird : 100

What should happen when it does not find the keywords is return "No Keywords Found"; however, it just doesn't return anything. No errors are reported, so it seems it just never sees the else statement as True if I'm understanding it correctly.

Any advice to get this to work would be greatly appreciated! Thank you in advanced!

Comment: What is the value of `keywords`?

Comment: How your `keyword_file_path` file looks like?

Comment: Looping `for key in kw_found.keys():` and then checking `if key in kw_found.keys()` is always gonna be true..

Comment: Won't it always evaluate to true though? You have `for key in kw_found.keys():` And your if statement is `if key in kw_found.keys()`: You are iterating through the keys and comparing a key to what you are iterating through. Your if statement needs to compare `key` to something else

Comment: FYI, you can use `data.count(keyword)` instead of a regular expression. If you want it to be case-insensitive, convert `data` and all the keywords to lowercase first.

Comment: What is this supposed to do? `width = max(len(x) for x in key)` `x` is each character in the `key`, so its length will always be 1.  This will always set `width = 1`

Answer (score 0):

```
    for key in kw_found.keys():
```

The above line will go through each element of `kw_found.keys()`, binding them to key.

```
        if key in kw_found.keys():
```

This asks if the thing we're looking at from `kw_found.keys()` is in `kw_found.keys()` - which, yes, it is.

```
            width = max(len(x) for x in key)
            output_fp.write("{0:<{1}} : {2}\n".format(key, width, kw_found[key]))
```

This next line will never fire. If `kw_found.keys()` is empty, the block it's in will never fire.

```
        else:
            output_fp.write("No Keywords Found\n")
```

Basically, you're mixing a list traversal where you inspect each element individually, with list comprehensions that deal with the entire list. You almost always want to use one or the other. Also, if you want to see if something is true *anywhere* in a list, you don't want an `if/else` block in your loop - that will evaluate the true branch correctly, but it will evaluate the false branch on each element that doesn't match the condition (even if it's matched elsewhere.) It's confusing "nowhere" with "not here".

Answer (score 0):

The observed behavior is correct. In your code, you are iterating over all detected keywords, which are stored in kw_found. And then you are checking if the current keyword is part of the dictionary you are iterating through. And this is always true.

Answer (score 0):

I'm new to this, but I think your for loop should be iterating through `keywords`, not `kw_found`. If it only looks at the keys that have been found, the if statement will always be right, and the else statement will never execute.

Here's the working code:

```
with open(keyword_file_path, 'r') as file:
    data = file.read()

kw_found = {}
for keyword in keywords:
    found = re.findall(keyword, data, re.I)
    if found:
        kw_found[keyword] = len(found)

for key in keywords.keys():
    if key in kw_found.keys():
        width = max(len(x) for x in key)
        output_fp.write("{0:<{1}} : {2}\n".format(key, width, kw_found[key]))
    else:
        output_fp.write("No Keywords Found\n")
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like that else statement is in the wrong loop:

```
with open(keyword_file_path, 'r') as file:
    data = file.read()

kw_found = {}
for keyword in keywords:
    found = re.findall(keyword, data, re.I)
    if found:
        kw_found[keyword] = len(found)
    else:
        output_fp.write("No Keywords Found\n")

for key in kw_found.keys():
    if key in kw_found.keys():
        width = max(len(x) for x in key)
        output_fp.write("{0:<{1}} : {2}\n".format(key, width, kw_found[key]))
```

Comment: Thanks all. I'm playing around with this and will update in a bit.

Answer (score 0):

After playing with this for a while, I finally got the else statement to trigger when the kw_found dictionary is empty. Now I get the expected output for the else statement when no keywords are found in the file.  I appreciate everyone's feedback and suggestions.

```
with open(keyword_file_path, 'r') as file:
    data = file.read()

kw_found = {}
for keyword in keywords:
    found = re.findall(keyword, data, re.I)
    if found:
        kw_found[keyword] = len(found)

if kw_found:
   for key in kw_found.keys():
       if key in kw_found.keys():
           width = max(len(x) for x in key)
           output_fp.write("{0:<{1}} : {2}\n".format(key, width, kw_found[key]))
else:
   output_fp.write("No Keyword Found \n")
```